# Awk find and replace for exact match only

Tags: regex, replace, awk

If I'd like to replace a character field, say **{**, with awk I can use:

```
awk '{ gsub(/{/, "<"); print }' file
```

...but this will also replace a field such as **"{"** (which I don't want). Is there an awk function which will find only an exact match (and replace) of an entire field; for all fields.

For example, the following:

```
$ echo "foo bar zod \"{\" {" | awk '{ gsub(/{/, "<"); print }'
```

will output:

```
foo bar zod "<" <
```

but I'd like it to output:

```
foo bar zod "{" <
```

I could also explicitly iterate over the fields and use **==** to check for an exact match, but I wonder if there's an alternative.

Comment: pls paste example input & expecting output

Comment: @Kent: This has now being added to the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would do what you said, loop through all field, either checking with `==` or `/^{$/`.

However if we play some trick, it could be done without loop: (gnu awk)

```
awk '$0=gensub(/(\s|^){(\s|$)/, "\\1<\\2","g")'
```

check this example:

```
kent$ echo '{ foo "{" and this: { bar {'|awk '$0=gensub(/(\s|^){(\s|$)/, "\\1<\\2","g")'
< foo "{" and this: < bar <
```

In the example above, 3 of 4 `{` were substituted.

Comment: Nice, the ^ and $ match the start and end of a string respectively; for when the sought character isn't preceded or followed by a space. The { in gensub's first argument doesn't correspond to \\2 as it isn't within parentheses.